# Element-wise operations on cell ranges in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets, what does one obtain if operations are performed on a range of cells? Have a look at the following example:

[image: Example: Adding 3 to a range]

Intuitively, I would expect the result to be 14. This is the way Matlab and similar languages behave. They perform the operation on each element.

There are two questions:

- What is happening here? What exactly am I computing the average of?
- Is there a way to obtain the expected behavior (other than creating a new range of cells with values increased by 3)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: To get the expected result, you should use `=AVERAGE(A1:E1) + 3`, not `=AVERAGE(A1:E1+3)`.

In effect, `A1:E1+3` is an expression that produces non-obvious results. Try inserting just `=A1:E1` in your `B3` cell, and it will return `4` (more on that below). Thus, `=A1:E1+3` is `7`, and `=AVERAGE(7)` is, well, `7`.

Another option is to use `=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:E1 + 3)`, which produces a new array where all elements are added with `3`, so that `=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:E1 + 3))` gives `14`.

It seems that an expression that consists of only a range (`A1:E1`) will return *the value of the range that corresponds to the current column*. I can't find any documentation for this behaviour, so I'm just guessing based on some experimentation.

If entering `=A1:E1` in different cells. In `C3`, it returns `9`. In `D3`, it returns `16`.
Entering a range that does not include the current column, e.g. `=A1:B1` in column `C`, returns a `#VALUE` error.

Feel free to look at [an example spreadsheet I used for experimentation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RUlrFpB6spXRmG0XZPNd3PNC2Yhah4L4MfwN5xYDLsk/edit?usp=sharing).

Edit: based on AdamL's confimation, this is a conclusive answer.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for this behaviour. Do you know any?

Comment: If you can't explain the behaviour, then why do you answer?

Comment: Well, I feel I have answered the actual questions: a) "What is happening here? What exactly am I computing the average of?" - you're computing the average of `7`, because `A1:E1` is `4` and `4 + 3` is `7` and b) "Is there a way to obtain the expected behavior" - yes, by modifying the formula slightly, or by using `ARRAYFORMULA`. The part I can't explain is why `A1:E1` returns the element corresponding to the current cell, but that was not strictly part of the question.

Comment: I also figured that out myself but couldn't explain the behaviour, thus I didn't answer, thus -1.

Comment: I can't explain the behaviour either Jacob, other than to say it is what it is. In all spreadsheet applications that I know of, if you reference a range when a single value is expected, and an array calculation enabler has not been used, then the value in the corresponding row or column is used (or a #VALUE error if there is no corresponding row or column). It would be like asking "why do SUMPRODUCT and LOOKUP not require Ctrl+Shift+Enter to perform array calculations in Excel?" I don't know the answer why... they just don't.

Comment: @pnuts, I can't think of an example of an *explicitly referenced range* exhibiting that behaviour (not to say there isn't one - would be interested to know if there is). Certainly, for arrays that are not explicitly referenced ranges (eg embedded arrays or arrays returned by a calculation), the first element of the array is used (but - to generalise a bit - often in these situations array calculations have already been enabled one way or another, so it can be a moot point).